# can we store some similar properties in different docuemts of same collection in cosmos DB container

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, data-modeling, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have two type of  documents user and group in same collection , user document have properties like userid, username , and user roles and group document have properties like groupid , name and users (who are part of that group) so can I have the same user information in both user and group documents or it should store user id in group document and fetch them again accordingly form user document via an API.
Below are the sample user and group documents

User :
{
"id": string,
"username" :string 
"roles: []
}

Group :

{
"id": string 
"groupName" :string 
"users" : []
}

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no "right" answer to this. How you design your document schema is going to be highly dependent on your read and write patterns. Also, the way you partition your container could have an impact on accessing your `user` and `group` documents, where your partitioning scheme is optimize for one type of document, and requires cross-partition queries for another type,

Answer (score 0):

You can do either ways but my recommendation would be to store just user ids in the group document. Here's my reasoning for that:

- If you were to edit a user (say change a role), then you will have to fetch group document, find the user, make the change there and then save it. Also, you would need to do the same in the user document as well. Thus you would end up updating 2 documents. This is considering a user belongs to just 1 group. If a user belongs to more groups, you would need to do the same for each group.
- Also, each document has a maximum size (2MB, I think). If you have large number of users in a group, then in no time you would exceed that limit.